# How to run Google Cloud Functions locally when emulator is built on Node 6 but Functions are deprecated for Node 6?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

The Google Cloud Functions emulator is only supported on Node 6:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator

> Note: The Emulator only supports Node v6.x.x. It does not support Node v8.x.x or Python."

But, Google Cloud Functions are deprecated for Node 6:  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-6-runtime

> The Node.js 6 runtime has been deprecated. To ensure that your functions are on a supported version of Node.js, migrate them to Node.js 8 or Node.js 10. After 2020-04-22, function deployments that use Node.js 6 will be blocked. Cloud Functions that continue to use Node.js 6 after this time may be disabled."

How do I go about running functions (written for Node 8) locally?

Comment: You should still be able to test your functions.  Your emulation environment just won't be exact.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960718/firebase-cli-functions-warning-no-engines-field-found-in-package-json-defau . The nodejs 6 runtime on Cloud Functions is now deprecated and is being removed.

Comment: @DougStevenson I ran the emulator and while there were no errors outright,  console.log() statements were not getting logged, the undeploy function wasn't working, etc. I couldn't tell if it was due to incompatible runtime (tried on Node 8 and Node 10 runtimes) or something else.

Answer (score 7):

Google has (April 2019) just released a new testing and development framework for Cloud Functions for Node.js based logic.  The name of this framework is called [Functions Framework for Node.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) and is opened sourced on Github.  If you visit the link just provided, you will find detailed documentation on how to download and use it.  At the highest (and summary) level:

1. `npm install @google-cloud/functions-framework`
2. Write your code.

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World');
};
```

3. Run your code using `npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=helloWorld`

While these are the cheat sheet notes, I strongly recommend reading the whole README docs at the Github repository.